# When two checkboxes are on the same page using the same class name, how do I check the box I want using nightmarejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, checkbox, nightmare

The DOM to use could be one of these two, they both are relevant to the box I would like to check:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="order[terms]" id="order_terms" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
```

or

```
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
```

There are two checkboxes with the same class name, so using:

```
.click('.iCheck-helper')
```

does not work, it checks the wrong box.

I'm thinking I have to be more specific to the box but every possibility I've come up with has failed. I run my program through node coded in atom and use nightmarejs as a dependant. I simply would like to check the correct box.

Comment: Why not access them by `id`?

Comment: @Scott How would I go about doing that? I tried: `.click('iCheck-helper[id="order_terms"]')` but does not work

Comment: It would need to be: `.click('.iCheck-helper[id="order_terms"]')` (notice that the selector starts off with a `.` because `iCheck-helper` is a class. Or, how about just: `.click('#order_terms')` since there should be only one item with that `id`?

Comment: @Scott you would get the error `Unable to find element by selector: .iCheck-helper[id="order_terms"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eq` pseudo selector as an option.

`.click('.iCheck-helper:eq(0)')` for the first and `.click('.iCheck-helper:eq(1)')` for the second.

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: Every time I try to use jquery in node I need jsdom, but I get the error `require(...).env is not a function` do you know how to fix that? @dgig

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not sure unfortunately.